# How to prove Playfair's axiom or Euclid's parallel postulate without using angle measure

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, axioms

I have only seen this proof done using angle measure.

How do you prove this without using angle measure or the fact that right angles are congruent?

Comment: Actually, they are two different problems. One is the weaker version of the other.

Comment: You can't prove Playfair, nor Euclid, from the other postulates. So you have to tell us what axiom system you are using.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to introduce angle measure. We use only the undefined intermediacy relation of point triplets. Also, we need the axioms describing the undefined concept of congruence making it possible to copy triangles (angles). Finally, we need the concept of perpendicularity.

See the following figure.

[image]

The definition of the relation $\beta>\alpha$ is based on that one can say that $B$ is between $A$ and $C$.
$\alpha=\beta$ if $C=B$. On the right hand side figure we define perpendicularity by $\alpha=\alpha'$.

---

Note that the Playfair axiom does not use angle comparisons. It is Euclid's Fifth postulate that uses the concept of angle comparison.

Answer (score 0):

I think that I can prove play fair's axiom in a very simple way. So just assume that there are two lines L1 and L2 passing through the same point and both of them are parallel to another line say L3. As L1 is parallel to L3 and L2 is also parallel to L3 then it can be proved simply that L1 is parallel to L2, but how is it possible because in the starting we had assumed them to have a common point. This contradicts our assumption. And hence we proved play fair's axiom